# Permanant extension for Fastener

Tags: design, fasteners

I have a fastener with an accessibility problem.  At the time of installation, the fastener is at the bottom of a crowded box with obstructions varying stiffness (Metal Plates and harnessing).  It is possible, but very inconvenient to position and drive the fastener using a [pick up tool](https://www.grainger.com/product/6TFG2), then drive the fastener with a long set of 1/4" drive socket extensions.

I'm thinking that a better solution would be a permanently installed drive tool which extended the fastener to the top of the box.  The solution I am imagining would leave the fastener placed permanently, or rather at an earlier stage of assembly, then allow the fastener to be driven without having to fish for the fastener from the top of the box.

Design Considerations

- The grip length of the fastener is unchanged
- Driving the fastener is the primary consideration
- A secondary consideration is positioning, the fastener remains in a slot and needs to be positioned in the slot to capture the thread on the far end.
- A bonus would be if the coupling allowed the screw to be driven without changing the depth of rod where it is being driven.  This would seem to require a coupling which could trasfer torque and also be telescoping.

To assist in imagination, I'll say that this is an 10-32x2" socket head fastener, driven from 18" away.

Possible Solutions:
 - Use an adhesive to bond a hex driver to the fastener then run a dedicated socket or bit extension to where it can be reached at the top of the box.
 - Weld a steel rod to the fastener.

Looking for better ideas and/or products which would make this easy to implement.

Comment: Can you just fasten it from the other end?

Comment: Fabricate or 3D print a lead-in cone. Then you just need to get your screwdriver in the vicinity to be able to line it up.

Comment: Use a [retaining washer](https://www.grainger.com/product/GRAINGER-APPROVED-Retaining-Washer-3XYX5) as a keeper on the outside of the box to hold the fastener. That lets you install the fastener earlier in the assembly. But it doesn't much help me when I try to take the darn thing apart. Next you're going to tell me it's right behind a magnetized  transformer - those are my favorite.

Comment: For a guide, you can take a bit of heat-shrink tubing and shrink it to the driver shaft leaving the open end big.